# Perfect secrecy within Android

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption

I am working at a non-profit health care project which will have an messenger build in.
Within the project I wanna add Perfrect Forward secrecy as part of security.
As I have read the documentation this is achieved by using the Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman (DHE) or the Ephemeral Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE) key exchange mechanism.
Correct me If I am wrong.

I'm trying to get an idea of ​​how it works exactly.
Unfortunately I can't find much information about how you can implement something like this within Android and mainly Kotlin.

At the moment I am using the following [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776709/kotlin-ecc-encryption) within Stackoverflow which has helped me a lot.

I also saw the term double-ratchet passing by, isn't that a bit the same? Since you can no longer decipher previous messages?

What are the first steps to implement the PFS algorithm if somebody has more information about this I will gladly follow it up?
As I am struggeling for days now.